# Ajuda com o código =SES

Tags: excel-vba, microsoft-excel

preciso de ajuda com essa formula no excel, estou tentando fazer uma comparação de valores em duas colunas primeira comparação seria na "G2" e a segunda comparação seria na "N2" com a função "SES e E" se caso os valores corresponderem ele coloca "Indefinido" ou os Estados, mas quando jogo no excel ele diz que a a formula não pode passar de 8128 caracteres, algum poderia me ajudar com esse código pf.

Codigo:

```
=SES(E(G2="NAVEGANTES"        ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="PORTO ALEGRE"           ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="CRICIÚMA"               ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="LAGES"                  ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="CHAPECÓ"                ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="SÃO JOSÉ"               ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="CASCAVEL"               ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="BLUMENAU"               ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="FLORIANÓPOLIS"          ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="CURITIBA"               ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="GUARAPUAVA"             ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="FOZ DO IGUAÇU"          ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="MARINGÁ"                ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="ARAUCÁRIA"              ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="PONTA GROSSA"           ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="LONDRINA"               ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="CANOAS"                 ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="GRAVATAÍ"               ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="NOVO HAMBURGO"          ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="CAXIAS DO SUL"          ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="JOINVILLE"              ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="CAMPO MOURÃO"           ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="PARANAVAÍ"              ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="ITAJAÍ"                 ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="TUBARÃO"                ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="BRUSQUE"                ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="PONTE ALTA"             ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="LAGUNA"                 ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="IÇARA"                  ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="JARAGUÁ DO SUL"         ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="XANXERÊ"                ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="CAPÃO ALTO"             ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="UMUARAMA"               ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="ROLÂNDIA"               ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="SÃO MATEUS DO SUL"      ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="ALTAMIRA DO PARANÁ"     ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="GUAÍRA"                 ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="APUCARANA"              ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="CAMPO LARGO"            ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="LAPA"                   ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="PATO BRANCO"            ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="DOUTOR ULYSSES"         ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="CÉU AZUL"               ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="ARAPONGAS"              ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="CIANORTE"               ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="QUEDAS DO IGUAÇU"       ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="TOLEDO"                 ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="PALHOÇA"                ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="CAMBORIÚ"               ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="BALNEÁRIO CAMBORIÚ"     ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="BIGUAÇU"                ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="GASPAR"                 ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="SÃO JOSÉ DOS PINHAIS"   ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="ALMIRANTE TAMANDARÉ"    ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="PINHAIS"                ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="SANTA CRUZ DO SUL"      ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="FARROUPILHA"            ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="CACHOEIRINHA"           ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="PASSO FUNDO"            ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="GUAPORÉ"                ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="POÇO DAS ANTAS"         ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="OSÓRIO"                 ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="GENERAL CÂMARA"         ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="VACARIA"                ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="COLINAS"                ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="SÃO LEOPOLDO"           ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="CACHOEIRA DO SUL"       ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="RIO GRANDE"             ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="PROTÁSIO ALVES"         ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="SÃO FRANCISCO DE PAULA" ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="SANTA MARIA"            ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="BENTO GONÇALVES"        ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="FRANCISCO BELTRÃO"      ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="QUATRO BARRAS"          ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="LAJEADO"                ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="VIAMÃO"                 ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="ALVORADA"               ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="ESTEIO"                 ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="GUAÍBA"                 ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="PELOTAS"                ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="INDAIAL"                ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="COLOMBO"                ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="FAZENDA RIO GRANDE"     ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="CAMBÉ"                  ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="CAMPINA GRANDE DO SUL"  ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="SÃO BENTO DO SUL"       ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="ESTÂNCIA VELHA"         ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="SAPUCAIA DO SUL"        ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="SAPIRANGA"              ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="ERECHIM"                ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="SARANDI"                ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="PAIÇANDU"               ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="MONTE CASTELO"          ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="MAFRA"                  ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="NOVA VENEZA"            ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="SANTA CECÍLIA"          ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="SÃO DOMINGOS"           ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="CONCÓRDIA"              ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="CURITIBANOS"            ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="MARILÂNDIA DO SUL"      ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="ANTONINA"               ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="IVAIPORÃ"               ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="BITURUNA"               ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="FOZ DO AREIA"           ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="MANOEL RIBAS"           ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="TRÊS DE MAIO"           ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="SANTO ÂNGELO"           ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="SANTA ROSA"             ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="MARIALVA"               ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="JABOTICABA"             ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="TORRES"                 ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="TRIUNFO"                ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="ENTRE RIOS DO SUL"      ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="IJUÍ"                   ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="PARANAGUÁ"              ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="MONTENEGRO"             ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="IVOTI"                  ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="DOIS IRMÃOS"            ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="CAPÃO DA CANOA"         ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="CAMPO BOM"              ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="CAMPO BOM"              ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="TAQUARA"                ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="CARLOS BARBOSA"         ;N2="M1");"INDEFINIDO";
E(G2="NAVEGANTES"             ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="PORTO ALEGRE"           ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="CRICIÚMA"               ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="LAGES"                  ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="CHAPECÓ"                ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="SÃO JOSÉ"               ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="CASCAVEL"               ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="BLUMENAU"               ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="FLORIANÓPOLIS"          ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="CURITIBA"               ;N2="V2");"PR CAPITAL";
E(G2="GUARAPUAVA"             ;N2="V2");"PR CAPITAL";
E(G2="FOZ DO IGUAÇU"          ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="MARINGÁ"                ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="ARAUCÁRIA"              ;N2="V2");"PR CAPITAL";
E(G2="PONTA GROSSA"           ;N2="V2");"PR CAPITAL";
E(G2="LONDRINA"               ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="CANOAS"                 ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="GRAVATAÍ"               ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="NOVO HAMBURGO"          ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="CAXIAS DO SUL"          ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="JOINVILLE"              ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="CAMPO MOURÃO"           ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="PARANAVAÍ"              ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="ITAJAÍ"                 ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="TUBARÃO"                ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="BRUSQUE"                ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="PONTE ALTA"             ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="LAGUNA"                 ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="IÇARA"                  ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="JARAGUÁ DO SUL"         ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="XANXERÊ"                ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="CAPÃO ALTO"             ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="UMUARAMA"               ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="ROLÂNDIA"               ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="SÃO MATEUS DO SUL"      ;N2="V2");"PR CAPITAL";
E(G2="ALTAMIRA DO PARANÁ"     ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="GUAÍRA"                 ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="APUCARANA"              ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="CAMPO LARGO"            ;N2="V2");"PR CAPITAL";
E(G2="LAPA"                   ;N2="V2");"PR CAPITAL";
E(G2="PATO BRANCO"            ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="DOUTOR ULYSSES"         ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="CÉU AZUL"               ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="ARAPONGAS"              ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="CIANORTE"               ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="QUEDAS DO IGUAÇU"       ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="TOLEDO"                 ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="PALHOÇA"                ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="CAMBORIÚ"               ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="BALNEÁRIO CAMBORIÚ"     ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="BIGUAÇU"                ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="GASPAR"                 ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="SÃO JOSÉ DOS PINHAIS"   ;N2="V2");"PR CAPITAL";
E(G2="ALMIRANTE TAMANDARÉ"    ;N2="V2");"PR CAPITAL";
E(G2="PINHAIS"                ;N2="V2");"PR CAPITAL";
E(G2="SANTA CRUZ DO SUL"      ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="FARROUPILHA"            ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="CACHOEIRINHA"           ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="PASSO FUNDO"            ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="GUAPORÉ"                ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="POÇO DAS ANTAS"         ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="OSÓRIO"                 ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="GENERAL CÂMARA"         ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="VACARIA"                ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="COLINAS"                ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="SÃO LEOPOLDO"           ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="CACHOEIRA DO SUL"       ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="RIO GRANDE"             ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="PROTÁSIO ALVES"         ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="SÃO FRANCISCO DE PAULA" ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="SANTA MARIA"            ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="BENTO GONÇALVES"        ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="FRANCISCO BELTRÃO"      ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="QUATRO BARRAS"          ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="LAJEADO"                ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="VIAMÃO"                 ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="ALVORADA"               ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="ESTEIO"                 ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="GUAÍBA"                 ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="PELOTAS"                ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="INDAIAL"                ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="COLOMBO"                ;N2="V2");"PR CAPITAL";
E(G2="FAZENDA RIO GRANDE"     ;N2="V2");"PR CAPITAL";
E(G2="CAMBÉ"                  ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="CAMPINA GRANDE DO SUL"  ;N2="V2");"PR CAPITAL";
E(G2="SÃO BENTO DO SUL"       ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="ESTÂNCIA VELHA"         ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="SAPUCAIA DO SUL"        ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="SAPIRANGA"              ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="ERECHIM"                ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="SARANDI"                ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="PAIÇANDU"               ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="MONTE CASTELO"          ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="MAFRA"                  ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="NOVA VENEZA"            ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="SANTA CECÍLIA"          ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="SÃO DOMINGOS"           ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="CONCÓRDIA"              ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="CURITIBANOS"            ;N2="V2");"SC";
E(G2="MARILÂNDIA DO SUL"      ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="ANTONINA"               ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="IVAIPORÃ"               ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="BITURUNA"               ;N2="V2");"PR CAPITAL";
E(G2="FOZ DO AREIA"           ;N2="V2");"PR CAPITAL";
E(G2="MANOEL RIBAS"           ;N2="V2");"PR CAPITAL";
E(G2="TRÊS DE MAIO"           ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="SANTO ÂNGELO"           ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="SANTA ROSA"             ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="MARIALVA"               ;N2="V2");"PR INTERIOR";
E(G2="JABOTICABA"             ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="TORRES"                 ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="TRIUNFO"                ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="ENTRE RIOS DO SUL"      ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="IJUÍ"                   ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="PARANAGUÁ"              ;N2="V2");"PR CAPITAL";
E(G2="MONTENEGRO"             ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="IVOTI"                  ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="DOIS IRMÃOS"            ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="CAPÃO DA CANOA"         ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="CAMPO BOM"              ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="CAMPO BOM"              ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="TAQUARA"                ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2="CARLOS BARBOSA"         ;N2="V2");"RS";
E(G2=""                       ;N2="");"DELETAR")
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

neste caso, ao invés de utilizar SE aninhado
poderia ser melhor utilizar uma tabela auxiliar com as cidades e as informações complementares (Indefinido/PR Interior).
Com isso você pode procurar os dados com um PROCV / PROCX.
E para seu último caso, célula vazia | Deletar, ai sim utilizar um SE.

A vantagem de utilizar essa tabela é que você pode substituir valores e fica mais fácil para outros usuários atualizar as informações.

Outro ponto: dependendo da sua base de dados, você também pode baixar a base do IBGE que tem a lista de cidades, códigos e estados também.